# holomorphic functions with nonvanishing derivative on unit disk $D$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, functions, conformal-geometry

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disk $D$. Suppose for any $z\in D$, $f'(z)\neq 0$. Then does $f$ have to be a conformal map from $D$ to $f(D)$?

Comment: By definition, a function on a complex domain is conformal if and only if it is holomorphic and its derivative is everywhere nonzero.  But if you're asking whether it has to be one-to-one, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take something like $f(z) = e^{10z}$. Then $f(0)=f(2\pi i/10)$, but $f'(z) \neq 0$ everywhere. (Assuming that you are asking whether $f$ has to be injective.)

Comment: @MikeMiller Why? There was no restriction on the image.

Comment: I misread the question as asking about conformal maps from the unit disc to itself. Sorry!